# Encrypt the item value in Oracle Apex URL

Tags: oracle, encryption, oracle-apex

I'm using apex 4.2 for creating my application but I'm now facing problems. How can I encrypt my item which I am appending to the url?

For example below is one of the url I'm talking about:

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=62577:4:7632245014057279::NO::P4_PERSON_ID,P4_ROLE:241.21

Here `P4_PERSON_ID`,`P4_ROLE` are my item but i need that item values should be passed as encrypt in my url.

How is it possible to do this?

Comment: can any one tell me how i can do this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the item values to show up in the URL, it might also be possible to use application items instead. These items are global for the current session and can be accessed from any page, and they do not show up in the URL. It is also possible to use state protection for these items such that they cannot be altered from the client.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be more sensible to use Session State Protection instead of encrypting your values. Not that it can't be done, but it's coding by hand. SSP does not encrypt, it generates a checksum for arguments and thus will not allow manually changing the values in the url.
[APEX Application Builder User's Guide: 15 - Understanding Session State Protection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/GUID-6522EA7B-299C-453A-90E4-70B7FFC7A856.htm#HTMDB12002)